# Cordova Depreciations in XCode 7 for Ionic app - what to do?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, xcode7

I'm converting my app update from a jQM version to Ionic and it's ready for release (finally).

I've released a small Ionic app already and it was really easy to do it with XCode (amazingly).

The new one has a successful build but there are loads of warnings about Depreciations and a few Value Conversion Issues.

I thought this might be my version of Cordova so I've updated, re-prepared for ios and tried again. I still get these warnings and Archive is greyed out so I'm guessing these are what is stopping me generate an .ipa.

Has anyone encountered this? Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

So I made a basic mistake - I'd selected a specific platform and not Generic device; that's why Archive was greyed out.

With regards to the depreciations - it seems they don't matter. My .ipa test file is running fine on two different iPhone models.